# beautifulsoup can't find exist href in file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html file like following:

```
<form action="/2811457/follow?gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37" method="post">
<div>
<a href="/2811457/follow?page=2&amp;gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37">next_page</a>
&nbsp;<input name="mp" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="page" size="2" style='-wap-input-format: "*N"' />
<input type="submit" value="jump" />&nbsp;1/3
</div>
</form>
```

how to extract the "1/3" from the file?

It is a part of html,I intend to make it clear.
When I use beautifulsoup,

I'm new to beautifulsoup,and I have look the document,but still confused.

how to extract"1/3" from the html file?

```
total_urls_num = re.findall('\d+/\d+',response)
```

work code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open("html.txt","r") as f:
    response = f.read()
    print response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    delete_urls = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('follow\?page'))   #works,should escape ?
    print delete_urls
    #total_urls_num = re.findall('\d+/\d+',response)   
    total_urls_num = soup.find('input',type='submit')   
    print total_urls_num
```

Comment: but when I change to (.*\d/\d.*),still doesn't work,it return None

Comment: How about `soup.find('input', value='jump).next`?

Comment: you mean like this:"total_urls_num = soup.find('input',value='jump').next",the return is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: That's odd, `soup.find('input',value='jump')` really should work.  Are you sure your soup contains the html you posted?  Can you fetch ANY tags from your input successfully?

Comment: @young001 what about soup.find(r"\d\/\d")

Comment: @Satoru.Logic,doesn't work too

Comment: I have paste my code,anyone can figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the text you're searching for isn't the attribute of some tag, but comes after.  You can access it using `.next`:

```
In [144]: soup.find("input", type="submit")
Out[144]: <input type="submit" value="jump" />

In [145]: soup.find("input", type="submit").next
Out[145]: u'&nbsp;1/3\n'
```

and you can then get the 1/3 from that however you like:

```
In [146]: re.findall('\d+/\d+', _)
Out[146]: [u'1/3']
```

or simply something like:

```
In [153]: soup.findAll("input", type="submit", text=re.compile("\d+/\d+"))
Out[153]: [u'&nbsp;1/3\n']
```

Comment: yours is exactly what I want,thx DSM,I should read beautifulsoup document more times.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Not

```
total_urls_num = soup.find('input',style='submit')   #can't work
```

You should use `type` instead of `style`

```
>>>temp = soup.find('input',type='submit').next
'&nbsp;1/3\n'
>>>re.findall('\d+/\d+', temp)
[u'1/3']
>>>re.findall('\d+/\d+', temp).[0]
u'1/3'
```